# minikube + kubernetes - unable to access the dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I am new to kubernetes and I have been experimenting with docker & minkube + kubernetes for a few weeks...

Everything appears to be working properly except the dashboard...These are my investigation but I have no clue how to fix this.

It is an out-of-the-box configuration, even with kubectl proxy with port 8001 don't work.

```
me@DEV ~ $ minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.0
me@DEV ~ $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
zollen@DEV ~ $ kubectl logs pod/kubernetes-dashboard-5498ccf677-hw574 --namespace=kube-system
2018/07/16 00:23:46 Starting overwatch
2018/07/16 00:23:46 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2018/07/16 00:23:46 Using service account token for csrf signing
2018/07/16 00:23:46 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2018/07/16 00:24:16 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
Refer to our FAQ and wiki pages for more information: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/

me@DEV ~/Downloads $ minikube dashboard 
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...

me@DEV ~ $ curl  https://10.96.0.1:443/version
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

me@DEV ~ $ kubectl proxy &
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

me@DEV ~/Downloads $ curl $(minikube ip):8001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.2.15 port 8001: Connection refused
me@DEV ~/Downloads $ curl localhost:8001
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta2",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta1",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/batch/v1beta1",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/extensions",
    "/apis/extensions/v1beta1",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/policy",
    "/apis/policy/v1beta1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/autoregister-completion",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/ca-registration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-informers",
    "/logs",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
    "/swagger.json",
    "/swaggerapi",
    "/version"
  ]
}

.
```

Comment: try minikube delete and recreate, minikube start

Comment: provide an output from `minikube status` command